# neo4j server is not restarting or stopping

Tags: neo4j

I am getting the following errors and I dont know how to restart the server .I tried multiple times but I get the same error all the time.How can I stop and restart the server.I really appreciate any help.

```
./bin/neo4j start
```

displays:

```
/usr/local/neo4j/data/log/console.log: Permission denied
process [11825]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.


sudo ./bin/neo4j start
```

displays:

```
Another server-process is running with [ST=ESTABLISHED], cannot start a new one. Exiting.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exception you get is because another server is running.

Also, there is another exception, you don't have write access in the folder for the logs.

1. Check if http://localhost:7474 is displaying the neo4j web browser.

If yes, locate the location of the running database :

[image]

Then go to the location and stop the db, eg based on the image :

```
cd /Users/cw/_graphs/tests
./bin/neo4j stop
```

If it is not working, try to kill the process :

```
sudo htop
```

[image]

```
kill -9 10522
```

And try to run your new database. And make sure you have the right permissions for the stores and logs.